# Как преобразовать выражение из строки в число (JS)

Tags: javascript

Как сделать так, чтобы в переменной Z выводился результат математических операций, а не просто строка.

Вот код:

```js
var z = 0;
var operat = ['+', '-'];
var rand1 = operat[Math.floor(Math.random() * operat.length)];
var rand2 = operat[Math.floor(Math.random() * operat.length)];

var reZ1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (10 - 1 + 1)) + 1;
var reZ2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (10 - 1 + 1)) + 1;
console.log(reZ1, reZ2);
z = z + rand1 + reZ1 + rand2 + reZ2;
console.log(z);
```

Answer (score 0):

можно использовать [`Eval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval)

```js
var z = 0;
var operat = ['+', '-'];
var rand1 = operat[Math.floor(Math.random() * operat.length)];
var rand2 = operat[Math.floor(Math.random() * operat.length)];

var reZ1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (10 - 1 + 1)) + 1;
var reZ2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (10 - 1 + 1)) + 1;

console.log("z =", z + rand1 + reZ1 + rand2 + reZ2);
z += eval(rand1 + reZ1 + rand2 + reZ2);
console.log(z);
```

а вот чтобы отсечь "баловство" пользователей на вход `Eval()` лучше действительно подавать результат регулярного выражения, в Вашем случае это цифры `\d` и `+-`
в качестве примера код оставил, он работает
но для более приближенных к жизни задач, рекомендуется замена строки на:
`z += eval((rand1 + reZ1 + rand2 + reZ2).match(/^[\d+-]*/g));`
или более быстрые альтернативы

Comment: Спасибо, помогло! С Новым годом!

Answer (score 0):

Тут есть два варианта. Первый вариант - `eval()`, второй - математика. Первый вариант - не из лучших в плане безопасности, но удобный(для разработчика).

Вот пример, как с помощью математики можно решить данную задачу:

```
var z = 0;
var operat = [1, -1];
var rand1 = operat[Math.floor(Math.random() * operat.length)];
var rand2 = operat[Math.floor(Math.random() * operat.length)];

var reZ1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (10 - 1 + 1)) + 1;
var reZ2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (10 - 1 + 1)) + 1;

console.log(reZ1, reZ2);
z = z + rand1 * reZ1 + rand2 * reZ2;
console.log(z);
```

ИЛИ

```
function rand(min, max){
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max-min + 1)) + min;
}
var z = 0,
    rand1 = Math.random()<0.5?-1:1;
    rand2 = Math.random()<0.5?-1:1;
    reZ1 = rand(10,1)*rand1,
    reZ2 = rand(10,1)*rand2;

console.log(reZ1, reZ2);
z = z + reZ1 + reZ2;
console.log(z);
```

Comment: Спасибо. Хороший вариант, тоже подходит!